# 'app_usbd_cfg.h: No such file or directory' error when adding header files to lpcxpresso

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to create a new project with lpc11u68 MCU for USB HID application based on the LPCOPEN sample project.

The problem is, the compiler can't recognize header files on the other folder. It shows this

```
error:../Main/src/Main.cpp:12:26: fatal error: app_usbd_cfg.h: No such file or directory
```

I've exactly done all of the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.lpcware.com/content/faq/lpcxpresso/creating-linking-library-projects) but the problem is still alive. When I copy all header and sources to the main directory of the project, it compiled correctly!

Comment: It is Eclipse, you should not be surprised when you get sudden strange linker errors or IDE bugs. These things happen constantly in LpcExpresso.

Comment: And how can fix it ?

Comment: So which include directories did you add when you followed steps 3-5?

Comment: Dear DiBosco I used LPCXpresso in my workplace and I have to use it ;( I'm agree about that!Any way I solved that & edit my question.Thank you all.

Comment: @MahmoudHD Answers are meant to be in the answer section. If you think this question may be helpful to future reader remove the answer part from the question and post an answer.

Comment: OK,Thanks for guidance,I edited it

Answer (score 0):

I was using quick setting -> include path for introducing my header's path to the Xpresso. This acts just as the instruction described in above tutorial, but only in C projects!

When you used that shortcut in C++ project, it adds paths to the C compiler Includes not to the C++ one! What an interesting bug!